# "signing product" Xcode freeze ONLY when refresh views

Tags: xcode

I deleted the derived data, but when I click on "Refresh all views" (because designable is updating) or Automatically refresh all views, it hangs on signing product. I can build and run the app perfectly. I had to force quit Xcode. This is the output when I try to restart Xcode and asking me to send this file to apple: https://ufile.io/j0uy1 (it is a .txt file) It is different from other questions about this, because I can build and run the application correctly, but this problem only occurs when refreshing views.